# JS Scoping issue

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope

Consider the following piece of code:

```
function processParagraph(paragraph) {
    if (paragraph.charAt(0) === '%') {
        for (var level = 0; paragraph.charAt(level) === '%'; level++) {}

        return {
            type: 'h' + level,
            content: paragraph.slice(level + 1)
        };
    }

    return {
        type: 'p' + level,
        content: paragraph
    };
}
```

When I check this with JSLint, it complains that `level` in the second return statement is `used out of scope.`.

But why? AFAIK, JavaScript has Lexical Scoping/Function Scope. As there are no nested functions, the code should be perfectly valid. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What's the value of 'level' if paragraph.charAt(0) does not equal '%'? Since the first declaration of "level" is within the if statement, it might be complaining about the possible use of a never-defined variable.

Comment: Are you sure that JSLint complains about this variable? This code is correct. Btw it would be better to declare variable on begining of function bacause this code is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One a variable is defined using `var` it is visible to the whole function.

What you have there will use `level` in the final return even though it has never been defined.

I would put

```
var level = 0;
```

...at the top of the function, and not declare it in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

JSLint is a Lint, not a plain syntax checker.

Function level scoping is something that many developers are not used to and don't expect. JSLint's author considers it good style to declare variables in such a way that they would still be compatible if block scoping were used.

Answer (score 1):

What it probably means is that `level` is not set, but used for the other execution path.